# How is the NULL pointer implemented on a linux system?

Tags: linux, pointers

Is it mapped to the zero page in memory?

Comment: @agou: No, the Windows VMM will not let you allocate a block with virtual address zero.

Comment: @agou `*(char*)0` is undefined behaviour, as it dereferences a null pointer (0 is a null pointer constant). If the address `0x00` is valid, to obtain a usable pointer to it, you must use a different method. But there's no portable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact it's Linux is irrelevant. In C the NULL constant is defined as '0' - zero. When a  process attempts to dereference a pointer whose value is zero in a protected mode context it causes an interrupt to be raised by the processor which is then handled by the OS (and then often passed up to the application's framework, which is why .NET gives you friendly NullReferenceExceptions but C gives you more cryptic errors).

Comment: So if you dereference it, it will try to access the zero page in virtual address space?

Comment: The value of a NULL pointer is not necessarily zero at runtime.  `char* p = 0;` always results in a NULL pointer, because you used an integral literal.  But `char* p; memset(&p, 0, sizeof p);` does not yield a NULL pointer on all conforming implementations.  Also, access violations are implementation-specific behavior -- all the Standard says about dereferencing unsafely derived pointers is that you get **undefined behavior**.  Ultimately, the platform is very relevant.